# BarCode Scanning Application

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Can anyone help me with this.I need a bar code scanning application for scanning product code.I am new to this.So send me an source code for the bar code scanner.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

Comment: That application is not works for my barcode.

Comment: now whats your requirement or what code works for you ?

Comment: If i scan any simple bar code means its displaying but if i scan any dim(i.e clarity low) it does not display

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps : 
[Android barcode scanner using Zxing](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/09/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing.html)

Comment: above is just link so please add some code with explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

Usage:

1. To initiate scan:

   ```
   new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // this is the current Activity
   ```
2. To get results:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (result != null) {
           if (result.getContents() != null) {
               String contents = result.getContents();
           }
       } else {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: how to get the image from the barcode in android

Comment: how to get image and text from code_128

Comment: Here you can find more info: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L440

Comment: how to set orientation to portrait in zxing in android.can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link for BarCode or QRCode Scanning

Visit https://github.com/zxing/zxing/

Comment: Have to import whole project or any example available in the zxing

Comment: how to get the image from the barcode in android

Comment: How to change the orientation of camera in zxing

Comment: you have to change orientation of camera through AndroidManifest.xml of zxing

Comment: I changed the code<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:stateNotNeeded="true"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">.But it is not displaying in portait mode